# Signing a transaction: string(22) "Internal Service Error"

Tags: transactions, keosd, signing

I'm using the jungle test chain jungle.eoscafeblock.com:8888 endpoint and import the private key to my local wallet, but when trying to get signature throuth local keosd api /v1/wallet/sign_signature ,it always return

["code"] => int(500)

["message"] => string(22) "Internal Service Error"

["error"] => array(4) {

```
["code"] => int(7)
["name"] => string(18) "bad_cast_exception"
["what"] => string(8) "Bad Cast"
["details"] => array(1) {
  [0] => array(4) {
    ["message"] => string(38) "Invalid cast from object_type to Array"
    ["file"] => string(11) "variant.cpp"
    ["line_number"] => int(545)
    ["method"] => string(9) "get_array"
  }
}
```

}

here is my request params

[{

```
    "expiration": "2019-08-30T08:04:31.500",
    "ref_block_num": 47006097,
    "ref_block_prefix": 727977150,
    "context_free_actions": [],
    "actions": {
        "account": "eosio.token",
        "name": "transfer",
        "authorization": {
            "actor": "morehandsome",
            "permission": "active"
        },
        "data": "a024c5699aa62e95a0229bfa4d37a98b010000000000000001454f5300000000086c75636b20677579"
    },
    "signatures": []
},
["EOS7r3k9iE5XtqWzxZwsNaXJ4pJjV84ksbVWBpBymfjn931R9kEEq"], "e70aaab8997e1dfce58fbfac80cbbb8fecec7b99cf982a9444273cbc64c41473"
```

]

is some where wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It appears your actions are not wrapped in an array. Actions parameter needs to be an array of objects (actions).

Try the adjusted format below.

```
[{

        "expiration": "2019-08-30T08:04:31.500",
        "ref_block_num": 47006097,
        "ref_block_prefix": 727977150,
        "context_free_actions": [],
        "actions": [{
            "account": "eosio.token",
            "name": "transfer",
            "authorization": {
                "actor": "morehandsome",
                "permission": "active"
            },
            "data": "a024c5699aa62e95a0229bfa4d37a98b010000000000000001454f5300000000086c75636b20677579"
        }],
        "signatures": []
    },
    ["EOS7r3k9iE5XtqWzxZwsNaXJ4pJjV84ksbVWBpBymfjn931R9kEEq"], "e70aaab8997e1dfce58fbfac80cbbb8fecec7b99cf982a9444273cbc64c41473"
]
```

Comment: it‘s wrapped.  the brackets are just outside the text box.  i didn't notice that . sorry

Comment: I don't mean the entire thing, I mean specifically the `actions`. Your code does not have an array for the actions parameter. My example does. If you test my example does it work?

Comment: Were you able to test this and verify my answer? If it worked for you, please accept the answer given, @WSQN